# Android Image upload to upload.im API

Tags: php, android, http, http-post

I need to upload an image from local directory to an API.

```js
private void uploadIm() {
  MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity();
  File image1 = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/finalImage.jpg");
  multipartEntity.addPart("upload", new FileBody(image1));
  HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://uploads.im/api");
  post.setEntity(multipartEntity);
  HttpResponse response;
  try {
   response = client.execute(post);
   HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
   String response_str = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
   Log.e("response", response_str);
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
```

This keeps giving me "connection reset by remote server" warning and shutting down. The API I am using is uploads.im, here are [Uploads.im](http://uploads.im/apidocs). I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here. Please help out or suggest an alternative. Thank you!

Comment: same problem here! do u solved it?